# Suppress Error Messages in PowerShell at get-package

Tags: windows, powershell

I use PowerShell to check, if specific apps are installed on the users PC:

```
$Application_MicrosoftEdge   = get-package "Microsoft Edge" | % { $_.metadata['installlocation'] }
$Application_Microsoft365    = get-package *"Microsoft 365"* | % { $_.metadata['installlocation'] }
Write-Host "Microsoft Edge Path    : $Application_MicrosoftEdge"
Write-Host "Microsoft 365 Path     : $Application_Microsoft365"
```

**This works quiet well**, but if an application is not installed on the users PC, then an error message is shown (here "Microsoft 365" is not installed on the PC):

```
get-package : Für "*Microsoft 365*" wurde kein Paket gefunden.
In D:\Scripts\GetInstalledApp.ps1:12 Zeichen:32
+ $Application_Microsoft365    = get-package *"Microsoft 365"* | % { $ ...
+                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power...lets.GetPackage:GetPackage) [Get-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.GetPackage
```

I tried the following way, but here an error message is shown:

```
Try {
  $Application_MicrosoftEdge   = get-package "Microsoft Edge" | % { $_.metadata['installlocation'] }
   $Application_Microsoft365    = get-package *"Microsoft 365"* | % { $_.metadata['installlocation'] }
}
Catch {
  # Place action on error here
}
```

I also tried to wrap it in `$( ... ) | out-null` to suppress the error, but this is also not working.
`
Any idea?

Comment: Add `-ErrorAction 'Stop'` to your command: `get-package *"Microsoft 365"* -ErrorAction Stop`. See [about exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-exceptions?view=powershell-7.2).

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to pass argument `Ignore` for [common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-7.2) `-ErrorAction` (`-EA`):

```sh
$Application_MicrosoftEdge   = get-package "Microsoft Edge" -EA Ignore | % { $_.metadata['installlocation'] }
$Application_Microsoft365    = get-package *"Microsoft 365"* -EA Ignore | % { $_.metadata['installlocation'] }

if( $Application_MicrosoftEdge ) {
    Write-Host "Microsoft Edge Path    : $Application_MicrosoftEdge"
}
if( $Application_Microsoft365 ) {
    Write-Host "Microsoft 365 Path     : $Application_Microsoft365"
}
```

On error, the pipeline output will be empty, which converts to `$false` in a boolean context, which we test using the `if` statements.

---

Alternatively, as [Abraham Zinala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14903754/abraham-zinala) commented, to make `try`/`catch` working, pass argument `Stop` for [common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-7.2) `-ErrorAction` (`-EA`) or set the [preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-7.2#erroractionpreference) `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` at the beginning of your script:

```sh
try {
    $Application_MicrosoftEdge   = get-package "Microsoft Edge" -EA Stop | % { $_.metadata['installlocation'] }
    $Application_Microsoft365    = get-package *"Microsoft 365"* -EA Stop | % { $_.metadata['installlocation'] }
}
catch {
    # Place action on error here
}
```

Using `-EA Stop`, errors are turned into script-terminating errors (exceptions), which **must** be caught using `try` / `catch`, otherwise the script would end prematurely.

Note that this code skips the 2nd `get-package` call, if the 1st one failed! This is because execution flow jumps straight from the first error location into the `catch` block. To handle errors separately for both `get-package` calls, you'd need two `try` / `catch` blocks.